# Problem with intval on numbers with more than 10 digits?

Tags: magento-1.7

I have to insert the last_trans_id of the last purchase made into a database. I am using initval() to change an integer to string but it ends up the same value like this 2147483647.

Any idea what else can i use i have tried these methods:

```
number_format($value['last_trans_id'], 0, '', '');

initval($value['last_trans_id']);

(string)$value['last_trans_id'];

number_format($value['last_trans_id']);
```

No success til now. any idea how to solve this? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can't cast this to int, because:

```
PHP_INT_MAX (integer)
The largest integer supported in this build of PHP. Usually int(2147483647). Available since PHP 4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5
```

[From the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)

[Working with large numbers in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211345/working-with-large-numbers-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the method `intval` instead of `initval`?
Also you use the intval value on the variable but you actually don't save the value that is returned from this.

Below some code that should do exactly what you want. Take an integer and make it a string.

```
$numberasstring = number_format((int)$value['last_trans_id'], 0, '', '');
var_dump($numberasstring); // this will be a string
```

Comment: Same result the var_dump turns string(10) "2147483647" same value.

Comment: What should it return? And what is the input value at first?

Comment: It should return a 10 digit number which is auto generated each time customer make a purchase, is called last_trans_id something like this: 2201270352

Comment: this kinda sounds like the issue is not in above code but in the source of the variable `$value['last_trans_id']`. If this should contain a random number and it isn't then the issue is where this variable is filled

Comment: Table column is VARCHAR length 60, I print everything after the success command and the trans_last_id is placed well on its own field , But when it comes into inserting it ends up blank on db. Also i try to replace it with custom value such as '1234567891' it goes successfully into db.

Comment: I think you need to post more code cause it sounds like the issue is coming from somewhere else than the code you've posted